# How to get the request parameters in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am very new to symfony. In other languages like java and others I can use `request.getParameter('parmeter name')` to get the value.

Is there anything similar that we can do with symfony2.
I have seen some examples but none is working for me. Suppose I have a form field with the name **username**. In the form action I tried to use something like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$username= $request->request->get('username');
```

I have also tried

`$username = $request->getParameter('username');`

and

```
$username=$request->request->getParameter('username');
```

But none of the options is working.However following worked fine:

```
foreach($request->request->all() as $req){
    print_r($req['username']);
}
```

Where am I doing wrong in using `getParameter()` method. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in line two: `$request->request-get()` should be `$request->request->get()`. Could that be it?

Comment: have written same in the code.missed out here.sorry for the typo here .still this is not working.

Comment: Have you (a) checked the manual to ensure that `get()` is the correct method and (b) turned on PHP notices so you can see if there are any problems? (c) Does Symfony 2 have a debug toolbar like symfony 1, so you can see if you've made any errors?

Comment: Are you confusing firstname and username?

Comment: There is more information here : https://roadtodev.com/recuperer-objet-request-de-symfony

Answer (score 453, accepted):

The naming is not all that intuitive:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    // $_GET parameters
    $request->query->get('name');

    // $_POST parameters
    $request->request->get('name');

    // As of 6.3 Posted or json content
    $request->getPayload()->get('name');
```

Update Nov 2021: [$request->get('name') has been deprecated in 5.4](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-controller-changes) and will be private as of 6.0.  It's usage has been discouraged for quite some time.

Update May 2023: As of 6.3, a [getPayload method](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-3-request-payload) has been added for post/json data.

Comment: It is different from what PHP uses, but it actually makes more sense. `$_GET` data is data from the query string (no `GET` request needed at all) and `$_POST` data is data from the request body (does not have to be a `POST` request either, could be `PUT`).

Comment: tried $request->query->get('name'); but it is also not working.

Comment: How do I get the parameters from a PUT request?

Comment: Very strange naming here, surely `$request->get` and `$request->post` would be simpler.

Comment: comment from igorw brings clarity to this freaky naming convention

Comment: But how to get the parameters of  PUT request? No docs found for it

Comment: If the URL in this format `http://localhost/c2Education/web/dailydata/payment?amount=1000` how can i access. is it right Way.? or any other alternate method to define url.

Comment: Mohammad - if you have the Request object as `$request` then do `$request->query->get('amount')`. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie currently, you can't, unless you do various workarounds, since neither PHP nor Symfony provides proper parsing for those requests (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464935/php-multipart-form-data-put-request etc)

Answer (score 34):

I do it even simpler:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $foo = $request->get('foo');
    $bar = $request->get('bar');
}
```

Another option is to introduce your parameters into your action function definition:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request, $foo, $bar)
{
    echo $foo;
    echo $bar;
}
```

which, then assumes that you defined {foo} and {bar} as part of your URL pattern in your routing.yml file:

```
acme_myurl:
    pattern:  /acme/news/{foo}/{bar}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Default:getnews }
```

Comment: and in the first example, if I have `foo` parameter both in query string and in POST body, which one will be returned by `$request->get('foo')`?

Comment: Looks like precedence is GET, PATH, POST http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: No it's not. The documentation of the method itself says it is discouraged to use it because it's heavier than accessing the GET/POST parameters through their specific collections.

Comment: **This answer is actually wrong!** `$request->get('foo');` will work for POST, but not for GET variables in Symfony2.

Comment: **Answer is correct** `$request->get('foo');` works for ALL bags (order is : PATH, GET, POST).
Nevertheless, `$request->request->get('foo');` works only for POST bag.
Finally, the first one (`$request->get()`) is not recommended if we know where the data is (GET/POST).

Answer (score 21):

You can Use The following code to get your form field values

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    // retrieve GET and POST variables respectively
    $request->query->get('foo');
    $request->request->get('bar', 'default value if bar does not exist');
}
```

Or You can also get all the form values as array by using

```
$request->request->all()
```

Comment: $request->request->all()
is working for me but something like $request->query->get('foo');
is not working.

Answer (score 13):

try

```
$request->request->get('acme_demobundle_usertype')['username']
```

inspect attribute name of your formular field

Comment: +1, since I think that of all the responses, only this one actually states the non-obvious thing - in cases you have created your forms automatically with help of symfony's form builder, symfony renames the form field to something more than you'd expect. Like name="acme_demobundle_userform[field_name]"

Comment: Syntax you mentioned here is not working with php 5.3.10. What is minimum version to support that?

Comment: @justinasLelys try

    $userType = $request->request->get('acme_demobundle_usertype');
    $username = $userType['username'];

Comment: @JustinasLelys Syntax is PHP 5.4

Comment: "username" can not be defined. So better check with "??" first.

Answer (score 9):

Inside a controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$username = $request->get('username');
```

Comment: In newer versions of Symfony, `$this->getRequest()` is deprecated, in favour of injecting the Request into the controller action, eg: `public function showAction(Request $request, $id);`

Answer (score 9):

As now `$this->getRequest()` method is deprecated you need to inject `Request` object into your controller action like this:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
```

after that you can use one of the following.

If you want to fetch POST data from request use following:

```
$request->request->get('var_name');
```

but if you want to fetch GET data from request use this:

```
$request->query->get('var_name');
```

Answer (score 9):

Your options:

1. Simple:

   - `$request->request->get('param')` (`$_POST['param']`) or
   - `$request->query->get('param')` (`$_GET['param']`)
2. Good Symfony forms with all validation, value transormation and form rendering with errors and many other features:

   - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html
   - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/index.html
3. Something in between (see example below)

```js
<?php
/**
 * @Route("/customers", name="customers")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $optionsResolver = new OptionsResolver();
    $optionsResolver->setDefaults([
        'email' => '',
        'phone' => '',
    ]);
    $filter = $optionsResolver->resolve($request->query->all());

    /** @var CustomerRepository $customerRepository */
    $customerRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer');

    /** @var Customer[] $customers */
    $customers = $customerRepository->findFilteredCustomers($filter);

    return $this->render(':customers:index.html.twig', [
        'customers' => $customers,
        'filter' => $filter,
    ]);
}
```

More about `OptionsResolver` - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this:

```
$clientName = $request->request->get('appbundle_client')['clientName'];
```

Sometimes, when the attributes are protected, you can not have access to get the value for the common method of access:

(POST)

```
 $clientName = $request->request->get('clientName');
```

(GET)

```
$clientName = $request->query->get('clientName');
```

(GENERIC)

```
$clientName = $request->get('clientName');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your answer to make it more readable next time and also check this help page: [answer]

Comment: what if there is 2 value after get ? like this `$clientName = $request->query->get('clientName','any');`

Answer (score 3):

Most of the cases like getting query string or form parameters are covered in answers above.

When working with raw data, like a raw JSON string in the body that you would like to give as an argument to `json_decode()`, the method [`Request::getContent()`](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getContent) can be used.

```
$content = $request->getContent();
```

Additional useful informations on HTTP requests in Symfony can be found on the [HttpFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/http_foundation.html) package's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For symfony 4 users:

```
$query = $request->query->get('query');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$getParameter = $request->get('getParameter');
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go for functions that do not have the `Request` parameter? (e.g. in private functions of the controller class for example)

Answer (score 1):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function indexAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $post = $request->request->all();

    $request->request->get('username');

}
```

Thanks , you can also use above code

Answer (score 1):

#www.example/register/admin

```
  /**
 * @Route("/register/{role}", name="app_register", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function register(Request $request, $role): Response
{
 echo $role ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need getting the value from a select, you can use:

```
$form->get('nameSelect')->getClientData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works

```
$this->request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

Regards

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The person asking the question already hast access to the request object.

Comment: @LaytonEverson sorry but you are mistaken, his method // $this->getRequest() is deprecated since 2.4, that's why it's not working, so he doesn't really have access to the request object ;)

Comment: Although you are not wrong about that, asker is wondering what method retrieves a variables from the request object. @Cerad answered this question correct. Not only did he provide the correct way to access the Request object, he also answer the question question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->get('corresponding_arg');
   // this also works
   $data1 = $request->query->get('corresponding_arg1');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.