# symfony2 request object get() function

Tags: php, symfony

I have a standard login form which I built with the createFormBuilder() method. When I try to
fetch input with

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('userName');
```

I get NULL beacuse $this->get('request')->request is a ParameterBag object who only has 'form' field with the input values. So when i do...

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('form')
```

i get the desired results but in an array

```
array(
    'userName' => 'Dude',
    'password' => 'password'
);
```

which is fine but is there a more intuitive way of fetching POST data?

I found this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784930/how-to-get-the-request-parameters-in-symfony2) but it didn't help.

I also tried with the Request object as a parameter in the controller method but with no results.

Comment: How is that *"not intuitive"*? You now KNOW that `request` contains `POST` data. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I started sympfony2 3 day ago and I remember that I could get the data with $request->get('userName'). I know that there's not one way to do something in symfony so I thought that there's another way to do this.

Comment: If you're trying to get `userName` directly from the request object, you can do `$request->request->get('form[userName]', null, true)` or `$request->get('form[userName]', null, true)`. Calling `Request::get` will look through `$request->query`, then `$request->attributes`, then `$request->request`

Comment: I tried that function but i didn't see the $default parameter. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$form->bind($request); $data = $form->getData(); echo $data['userName']`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I will firstly verify whether a form is valid or not. Then,  I will bind the form object and use that form to get some data. So, the code should be looked like following:

```
if ($request->getMethod('post') == 'POST') {
        // Bind request to the form
        $form->submit($request);
        // If form is valid
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Get data from the userName field
            $username = $form->get('userName')->getData();            
        }
}
```