# Symfony2 - Ajax Search

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony2 project where I have a user entity and I need an ajax search bar to search for my users.
The problem is that in my AJAX response the controller, for some reason, returns all users from the database.

js

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

     searchText = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Apana/web/app_dev.php/search",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {searchText : searchText},
        success : function(response) 
          {
                console.log(response);
          }
    });
});
```

The controller

```
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

use Apana\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\User;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    public function liveSearchAction(Request $request)
    {

        $string = $this->getRequest()->request->get('searchText');
        //$string = "alfa";
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('ApanaMainBundle:User')
                     ->findByLetters($string);

        //return users on json format

        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($users, 'json');

        $response = new Response($jsonContent);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

User Repository

```
    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findByLetters($string){
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u FROM ApanaMainBundle:User u  
                WHERE u.firstname LIKE :string OR u.lastname LIKE :string')
                ->setParameter('string','%'.$string.'%')
                ->getResult();
    }
}
```

If I give a static text for my string parameter and visit the route for the controller, it works fine.

Comment: Did you check that the value is getting passed to javascript ?  You might also want to try with `type: "POST"`and try sending back the string for debug.

Comment: Strange, just changed the type to "POST" ... and works perfect !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer was to change the following:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        [...]
```

To

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        [...]
```

It is not that strange you just probably weren't actually getting the GET parameter: [How to get the request parameters in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784930/how-to-get-the-request-parameters-in-symfony2)

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    // $_GET parameters
    $request->query->get('name');

    // $_POST parameters
    $request->request->get('name');
```

And there are a couple other possible methods mentioned there. It would have solved your problem too but it is always better not to use GET if you don't have to.