# How can I update my entity using POST method without form in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Controller , I can't found how using POST method without form in this part

```
public function validerReservationAction(Request $request,$id) {    
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $reserv = $em->getRepository('LacarteRestBundle:Reservation')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

      if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
          // $reserv = $_POST['OkResto'];     
            $reserv->setOkResto(1);
            $em->persist($reserv);
            $em->flush();
    }
            return $this->FindAllRsvAction();
        }
```

routing yml

```
  lacarte_rest_validerRsv:
            path:     /tableRsv/{id}
            defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validerReservation }
```

This is the view

```
<a href="{{ path('lacarte_rest_validerRsv', { 'id': reservation.id })}}" title="Valider"><i class="splashy-check"></i></a>
```

Comment: $request->request->get('OkResto'); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784930/how-to-get-the-request-parameters-in-symfony2/9788435#9788435

Comment: I try it before and doesn't work for me:

Comment: I try this; if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
          
             $request->request->get('OkResto');
            $reserv->setOkResto(1);
            $em->persist($reserv);
            $em->flush();
        }

Comment: Consider updating your question with your actual code.  If you are indeed posting a OkResto then the code shown in the comment will work.  Might use F12 in the browser or perhaps the profile bar to determine what exactly is being posted.

Comment: By the way, the twig template strongly suggests you are issuing a GET request and not a post.  Maybe show your form.

Comment: I change my path like that but i still some mistake in controller, how coud i setOkResto(1) manually with post method:              lacarte_rest_validerRsv:
            path:     /tableRsv
            defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validerReservation }

Comment: Start by reading your own comments.  Can you make any sense out of them?  Comments are not really good for multiple lines of code.  Hit the edit button under your question and update it with your actual code so we can read it.

Comment: Furthermore, I am beginning to suspect that you want an html href to generate a POST request?  Not going to happen.  You need an html form or perhaps some java script.

Comment: I'm using twig in href, it try it before to call path. i need to know how could i setOkResto(1) with post method

Comment: You need to use a form to generate a POST request.  Either use the Symfony form component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) or change your template to generate a html form element.  If you don't understand this then you need to step back and find a introduction to html tutorial.  You won't get very far without at least a basic understanding of html.  This might also help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the getter function of the request object, it will retrieve the correct value, doesnt matter if post or get

```
  if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
        $reserv->setOkResto($request->get('OkResto'));
        $em->persist($reserv);
        $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: How could i set the content of setOkResto(1);