# Ajax and DefaultController Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I use Symfony 3 and I try to call my function in the Default Controller with Ajax like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'active'
        },
        url: '{{ path ('
        show_chat ')}}',
        success: function(active) {
            if (active === true)
                $('.message-box').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

In the Default Controller I want to return a twig template and a variable which is true so my window for the chat can appear:

```
return $this->render('ChatBundle:Default:chat.html.twig',$online);
```

I use  `$presence = $request->get('active');`  `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`

My method is POST but when I dump $request the method is GET. I do not understand what I am doing wrong and why it doesn't work ... Any ideas, please

Routing:

```
show_chat:
path:     /chat
defaults: { _controller: slackChatBundle:Default:chat}
methods: [POST,GET]
```

If I put only POST method ,I have a message "No route found,Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

this is the dump of request:

[dump request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea07P.png)

Comment: the request method is Post ..

Comment: You are getting it correctly. Just look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788435/2236219. Both GET & POST methods having the different way to be accessed in the controller.

Comment: I saw this answer, I have tried but still it doesn't work

Comment: I have used   both  $request->query->get('name');
and 
    $request->request->get('name')  but none of them seems to do the job. That is why I have no idea what is wrong with my code

Comment: Cou give us a dump of `$request` in question?

Comment: Try with `method` instead of `type` in your Jq ajax call. Check in your browser `dev tool > network > xhr` if the request have the good HTTP verb

Comment: Mcsky, thank you for the proposition ,but it doesn't work...all seems fine in network , I can see the action  the method .

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more specific dumps request->request & request->query ?

And related to following post, I agree you should use FOSJsRoutingBundle. It let you expose symfony routing.

Comment: I add a photo of dump $request. It is with Get,everything is empty

Comment: Ok I can comment now, I need theses specific dumps to see if problem come from js (probably routing) or from your controller

Comment: Karael, Thank you very much for your advices  ...I managed to find a solution ..I did not changed a lot, I  assign  the variable to JsonResponse : $response = new JsonResponse($online) and I returned it 
return $response,no render   and  just work,suprise.... I do not know if it is good approach but it does work. ..Now I will  use FOSJsRoutingBundle, because I have to make an ajax call from the js

Answer (score 0):

I advice that you use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) that allows you to expose Symfony Routes to JavaScript