# moving temp file after upload wont work

Tags: php, angularjs

Before everything , I know that my question is already posted thousand times but none of them concern me since i cant identify my problem.

So ,I am building  a PHP rest api to get a put request from the client (angular), this last can update a file inside the form as well as some text inputs , all of this is sent as a [form-data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)  in this code :

```
var fileFormData = new FormData();
$http({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: host + '/produit/' + $scope.product.id,
  data: fileFormData,
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {}, function errorCallback(response) {});
```

On the server-side I have to get the response type and then parse the data here's the full code with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464935/php-multipart-form-data-put-request)

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method=="PUT"){
global $_PUT;

/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
// $fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

$raw_data = '';

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($chunk = fread($putdata, 1024))
    $raw_data .= $chunk;

/* Close the streams */
fclose($putdata);

// Fetch content and determine boundary
$boundary = substr($raw_data, 0, strpos($raw_data, "\r\n"));

if(empty($boundary)){
    parse_str($raw_data,$data);
    $GLOBALS[ '_PUT' ] = $data;
    return;
}

// Fetch each part
$parts = array_slice(explode($boundary, $raw_data), 1);
$data = array();

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    // If this is the last part, break
    if ($part == "--\r\n") break;

    // Separate content from headers
    $part = ltrim($part, "\r\n");
    list($raw_headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $part, 2);

    // Parse the headers list
    $raw_headers = explode("\r\n", $raw_headers);
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($raw_headers as $header) {
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header);
        $headers[strtolower($name)] = ltrim($value, ' ');
    }

    // Parse the Content-Disposition to get the field name, etc.
    if (isset($headers['content-disposition'])) {
        $filename = null;
        $tmp_name = null;
        preg_match(
            '/^(.+); *name="([^"]+)"(; *filename="([^"]+)")?/',
            $headers['content-disposition'],
            $matches
        );
        list(, $type, $name) = $matches;

        //Parse File
        if( isset($matches[4]) )
        {
            //if labeled the same as previous, skip
            if( isset( $_FILES[ $matches[ 2 ] ] ) )
            {
                continue;
            }

            //get filename
            $filename = $matches[4];

            //get tmp name
            $filename_parts = pathinfo( $filename );
            $tmp_name = tempnam( ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'), $filename_parts['filename']);

            //populate $_FILES with information, size may be off in multibyte situation
            $_FILES[ $matches[ 2 ] ] = array(
                'error'=>0,
                'name'=>$filename,
                'tmp_name'=>$tmp_name,
                'size'=>strlen( $body ),
                'type'=>$value
            );

            //place in temporary directory
            file_put_contents($tmp_name, $body);


        }
        //Parse Field
        else
        {
            $data[$name] = substr($body, 0, strlen($body) - 2);
        }

    }

}
$GLOBALS[ '_PUT' ] = $data;
 $input= array_merge($_PUT, $_FILES);
 }
```

and then I have to execute the query and move the file form the temp folder

```
$sql = "update `$table` set $set where id=$key"; //works    
if(isset($name)){ //to check if file exist
chmod($tmpname,0666); //since that's the answer for most of question that are similar to mine
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($tmpname)), -4); //returns 0666
echo $tmpname." ".$name; //works too
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "/home/****/****/uploads/produits/".$name))
echo "moved";
else 
echo "not moved"; // and I always get this
```

Can you explain to me please whats wrong ?

PS: 
I checked the `/tmp` folder the files I uploaded are still there.
The log is clean and I used this in the top of my code

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Update :

I use this to get file params from the `$input` var

```
$values = array_map(function ($value) use ($link) {
     global $method;
    if ($value === null)
        return null;
    if (gettype($value) === "array"){
         if ($method=="PUT" || $method=="POST"){            
        global $tmpname,$name;
        $tmpname=$value['tmp_name'];
        $name=uniqid().$value['name'];
       $value=$name;
         }
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $value);
}, array_values($input));
```

Comment: Checked your servers error log?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No thing i already have `ini_set('display_errors', true);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of my code

Comment: this is a real path you put? `/home/****/****/uploads/produits/`

Comment: @JesusCarrasco no i just his what i dont want to show the real one works fine for the post request

Comment: oks, so you verify that paths exists. but still file not move, the permissions to the final path, has the rights to write ?.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco yes sure i am already using it in other requests

Comment: Just curious, why are you first saving the file in the temp folder and then move it to another folder? Why not store it in the correct location to start with?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Interesting idea ! i didn't even think about that and i will try it if there will no solutions here. i just want the explanations why the file wont move

Comment: There are a few questions. For example, where do you set some of the variables you're using in the code that moves (or should move) the file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Check the update