# Symfony / API Platform - Custom Operation - PUT method for file replacement using VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com, vichuploaderbundle

I am using Vich Uploader Bundle in combination with API Platform to store files. I've followed the instructions from the official documentation 
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/#handling-file-upload

Everything works well except I want to include PUT calls to replace existing MediaObject entities. My attempt was as follows:

I have created a custom operationand mapped it to the PUT method in the entity as follows:

```php
<?php
// api/src/Entity/MediaObject.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\CreateMediaObject;
use App\Controller\EditMediaObject;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 * 
 *     ...
 * 
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put"={
 *             "controller"=EditMediaObject::class,
 *             "deserialize"=false,
 *             "validation_groups"={"Default", "media_object_create"},
 *             "swagger_context"={
 *                 "consumes"={
 *                     "multipart/form-data",
 *                 },
 *                 "parameters"={
 *                     {
 *                         "in"="formData",
 *                         "name"="file",
 *                         "type"="file",
 *                         "description"="The file to upload",
 *                     },
 *                 },
 *             },
 *         },
 *         "delete"
 *     },
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class MediaObject
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ApiProperty(iri="http://schema.org/contentUrl")
     * @Groups({"media_object_read"})
     */
    public $contentUrl;

    /**
     * @var File|null
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"media_object_create"})
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media_object", fileNameProperty="filePath")
     */
    public $file;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    public $filePath;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

The correponding Controller:

```php
<?php
// api/src/Controller/EditMediaObject.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\MediaObject;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

final class EditMediaObject
{
    /**
    * @var RequestStack
    */
    private $requestStack;


    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }
    public function __invoke(MediaObject $data): MediaObject
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $uploadedFile = $request->attributes->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException ('"file" is required');
        }
        $data->file = $uploadedFile;

        return $data;
    }
}
```

The $data object is susccessfully populated. However I dont have access to the initial request parameters (particularly 'file').

Is this because of the preliminary OPTIONS call? If so, how can I forward / preserve the file to attach it to the MediaObject?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

In case anyone is interested, it is NOT possible to send file parameters over PUT requests in PHP. (source: [PHP multipart form data PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464935/php-multipart-form-data-put-request/9469615#9469615))

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking at `$request->attributes`?
You should be looking at `$request->files`.

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data

Comment: Thank you, but the FileBag is also empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a POST request with an extra parameter, `_method = PUT`, It will change the POST request as if it is a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a very similar problem, though, I'm not using the entire symfony library, I'm using the `HttpFoundation/Request` and `HttpFoundation/Response` objects.

At first I was puzzled by how the request seemed completely empty.

After spending more time than I would have liked looking into it, this is an issue that can be traced back to the internals of PHP.

I managed to find [this PECL extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/apfd)

I'm not really very familiar with pecl, and couldn't seem to get it working using pear. but I'm using CentOS and Remi PHP which has a yum package.

I ran `yum install php-pecl-apfd` and it literally fixed the issue straight away. I believe there are other packages in various flavours of linux and I'm sure anybody with more knowledge of pear/pecl/general php extensions could get it running on windows or mac with no issue.

By fixed, I mean, my request object was populated as expected (`request->all()` and `request->files` for example).

This seems to have worked for both `PUT` and `PATCH` requests with and without files (using multipart forms).

If you're using Docker, you'll need to restart your containers.