# Cannot get PUT request with file upload to work

Tags: php

My application needs to upload files using POST and PUT methods and I ran into the PHP limitation that it doesn't natively support file uploads in a PUT call.  I found some code that provides that ability in a stack overflow post at [PHP multipart form data PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464935/php-multipart-form-data-put-request).  it seems to create correctly formatted $_FILES data.

The POST and PUT methods in my application both use a common function to upload the file to my server.  The POST method works correctly but the PUT method fails returning false with an error code of zero.  Here is the code.

```
function processPhoto($file, $bmid)
{
$x = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$filetype = $x[1];
$fileurl = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/assets/img/bm$bmid-" . date('Ymd') . ".$filetype";
$filedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/img";
$filepath = $filedir . "/bm$bmid-" . date('Ymd') . ".$filetype";

if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets")) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "/assets is not a directory");
}
if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/img")) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "$filedir is not a directory");
}
if (!is_writable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets")) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "/assets is a directory but is not writeable");
}
if (!is_writable($filedir)) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "$filedir is a directory but is not writeable");
}

if (!file_exists($file["tmp_name"])) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "$file[tmp_name] does not exist");
}

clearstatcache();
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    chmod($filepath, 0755);
    unlink($filepath);
}

$result = move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $filepath);
if (!$result) {
    return array('result' => false, 'message' => "Unable to upload the photo file from  $file[tmp_name] to $filepath (error #$file[error])");
}
return array('result' => true, 'filename' => $fileurl);
}
```

The $file parameter contains the data from $_FILES['myfile'].

From other SO posts, it seems that the combination of a false return from move_uploaded_file and an error of zero is often caused by permission problems on the target directories where the file is stored but my code checks for that, plus the directories are the same for the POST and PUT requests and the POST request works. I also tried using exif_get_data() on the temp file (it's a jpeg) and it returns correct data for the file.

The lack of information provided by move_iuploaded_file() when it fails makes it hard to figure out what the problem is so I'd be grateful for any ideas on what might be causing this.

Comment: The difference between POST and PUT is that you don't need to use the emulation code to handle POST. So that code is apparently not creating the temp file the same way that PHP does it automatically for POST. It's probably related to ownership or permissions, you'll need to check what's different.

Comment: Maybe what the manual for `move_uploaded_file` says, is meant literal? _"This function checks to ensure that the file designated by from is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism)."_ - if(?) that check _demands_ the request method was POST, then you might simply need to use a different function to move the file from the temp dir to the target location, for your PUT request.

Comment: Cbroe's comment put me on the right track.  I ended up using copy() instead of move_uploaded_file() if the request is a PUT and that worked